# Is there a way to query Metaplex token metadata?

Tags: metaplex, metadata, query

I was wondering if there was a way to get the metadata for NFT tokens minted through the Metaplex standard? I was able to find the data for Solana fungible tokens using the code listed below and I want to find the same kind of data but just for Metaplex NFTs.

```
import { TokenListProvider } from '@solana/spl-token-registry';

function App() {
new TokenListProvider().resolve().then((tokens) => {
  const tokenList = tokens.filterByClusterSlug('mainnet-beta').getList();
  console.log(tokenList);
})
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep you can use the Helius API to get all token metadata! See the [docs](https://docs.helius.dev/solana-apis/token-metadata-api) for nft metadata. You can get an API key [here](https://dev.helius.xyz/dashboard/app)

Some example code for how to do this

```
const axios = require('axios')

const url = "https://api.helius.xyz/v0/tokens/metadata?api-key=<your-key>"
const nftAddresses = [
  "BAAzgRGWY2v5AJBNZNFd2abiRXAUo56UxywKEjoCZW2",
  "8s6kQUZfdm7GSaThAcsmSs56wMinXrbk6SdNVngutrz5"
] // Monkes
const getMetadata = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.post(url, { mintAccounts: nftAddresses})
  console.log("metadata: ", data)
}
getMetadata()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `findByMint` method from the Metaplex SDK:
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#findByMint
[image]

Comment: this looks like it'll work. Do I need to have a public key? Or can I just leave that string open to get all of them?

Comment: take a look at `findAllByMintList` if you're trying to fetch in bulk. https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#findAllByMintList