# I need to get the creator of an SPL token that has been minted already

Tags: spl-token

What I'm basically trying to do is what [Rugcheck](https://rugcheck.xyz) does. When given a token address, it shows the creator of that token. My initial approach was getting all transactions of the token with `getSignaturesForAddress` from the @solana/web3.js library, then reversing the array and finding the first transaction without an error. That only works sometimes and I don't know why. I'm new to this and completely clueless. What's a better way to get an SPL Token Program's (`TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`) creator?

Take for example this token: `7ayGpQ5NbMNeBSXsJWuWE6ZQ7y1f37UGSaHUc4fGypgd`
My code returns the creator correctly for this.

But then the same code returns the wrong creator for this: `CYQqL1bdkL2zB1mJfi88jk2bsps2UbMC1iSLqJr8Gr16` (I'm assuming that rugcheck returns the correct creator.)

Here's the code I currently have. I don't know if it's good or bad. I'm only experimenting.

```
async function getCreator(tokenAddress: string): Promise<string> {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));

  // Get the transaction signatures involving the token address
  const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
    new PublicKey(tokenAddress)
  );

  if (signatures.length === 0) {
    console.log("No transactions found for this address");
    return "no transactions found";
  }

  // reverse the array to get the first transaction
  signatures.reverse();

  // Retrieve the first transaction signature by iterating and returning the first one that has err: null
  const firstSignature = signatures.find(
    (signature) => signature.err === null
  )?.signature; // Add null check using optional chaining operator

  console.log(firstSignature);

  //   Get the transaction details
  const transaction = firstSignature
    ? await connection.getParsedTransaction(firstSignature, {
        maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
      })
    : null;

  console.log(transaction);

  const signer = transaction?.transaction.message.accountKeys
    .map((key) => key.pubkey.toBase58())
    .filter((key) => key !== tokenAddress)[0] as string; // Add type assertion to ensure 'signer' is of type 'string'

  return signer;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to query Metaplex token metadata?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/is-there-a-way-to-query-metaplex-token-metadata)

Answer (score 1):

For what you're wanting to achieve, you want to inspect the token meta-data. The answer to this question - [Is there a way to query Metaplex token metadata?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/is-there-a-way-to-query-metaplex-token-metadata) - has what you need.

I would personally recommend the Helius API answer as it is low-lift implementation.

Here's an example response from their API based on the code example and the token accounts you provided in your question - the key thing to look out for here is `updateAuthority`:

```
metadata:  [
  {
    mint: '7ayGpQ5NbMNeBSXsJWuWE6ZQ7y1f37UGSaHUc4fGypgd',
    onChainData: {
      tokenStandard: 'Fungible',
      key: 'MetadataV1',
      updateAuthority: '6EBfw9vJd3xsiMLYsKp4zEQi7986xjMh3uvc2WjmkG7A',
      mint: '7ayGpQ5NbMNeBSXsJWuWE6ZQ7y1f37UGSaHUc4fGypgd',
      data: [Object],
      primarySaleHappened: false,
      isMutable: true,
      editionNonce: 254,
      uses: [Object],
      collection: null,
      collectionDetails: null
    },
    offChainData: {
      description: "There's no better host for the Year of the Dragon than Pepenite. Come join the party and set the new trend for 2024 with $PNITE! - https://t.me/PepeNite | https://twitter.com/PepeniteSol",
      image: 'https://bafkreihvqlebzgcxkobgsimcrccbms5mn5wn3z4zspppi73ofzd7yv5epa.ipfs.nftstorage.link',
      name: 'Pepe Nite',
      symbol: 'PNITE'
    }
  },
  {
    mint: 'CYQqL1bdkL2zB1mJfi88jk2bsps2UbMC1iSLqJr8Gr16',
    onChainData: {
      tokenStandard: 'Fungible',
      key: 'MetadataV1',
      updateAuthority: 'EpFWDb9CQ36ScN32xvzJrbgztbP1SM5rtLUaTsrE9JxN',
      mint: 'CYQqL1bdkL2zB1mJfi88jk2bsps2UbMC1iSLqJr8Gr16',
      data: [Object],
      primarySaleHappened: false,
      isMutable: true,
      editionNonce: 255,
      uses: [Object],
      collection: null,
      collectionDetails: null
    },
    offChainData: {
      description: 'Squirtlesaxophonesol.com',
      image: 'https://bafkreifemv36x6awzi6sdmxkh52jriwomll7j7rabluhzwoyy4v7qa7b6u.ipfs.nftstorage.link',
      name: 'Squirtle Saxophone',
      symbol: 'Saxoph'
    }
  }
]
```

As for why your solution wasn't returning expected responses, there are not many transactions involving `7ayGpQ5NbMNeBSXsJWuWE6ZQ7y1f37UGSaHUc4fGypgd`, so when you get them - you get them all going back to the creation of the token, so reversing the list gives you the first transaction.

But `CYQqL1bdkL2zB1mJfi88jk2bsps2UbMC1iSLqJr8Gr16` has a lot of transactions associated with it so you're only getting recent transactions, not all of them, meaning the last one in the list isn't necessarily the first-ever transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dru! I did find out about Helius' API as well. But I'm also trying to find a solution using SDKs instead of APIs. Do you have any solution in mind for that? Only coins, not NFT

Comment: No worries, I believe the metaplex sdk answer in the original linked answer should give you what you need - https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/2460/7498

Comment: Yep. I used metaplex-token-metadata's SDK to get the token's metadata using the fetchDigitalAsset method. Appreciate the help!